# Parse - Swift : Concatenate Queries

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm creating an iOs app with Swift and Parse.com. Unfortunately, i've a problem when I build my query.

What I want : I have a class with sport's players (with goals and passes). I would like to retrieve the player with the most goals and the player with the most passes. I have two columns in my Parse class : goals and passes.

So, for me, I would use

```
query_goals.limit = 1 
query_goals.orderByDescending("goals")

query_passes.limit = 1
query_passes.orderByDescending("passes")
```

and now I need to concat the two queries but I didn't find anything for that in swift iOS documentation...

Does anyone have an idea please ? :)

EDIT : 
I want to print the best scorer and passer in collectionView cells :

```
override func queryForCollection() -> PFQuery {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "liste_joueurs")
    query.limit = 1
    query.orderByDescending("goals")

    let query_passes = PFQuery(className: "liste_joueurs")
    query_passes.limit = 1
    query.orderByDescending("passes")

    let final_query = query + query_passes //Swift Concat to illustrate my purpose

    return final_query
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject!) -> PFCollectionViewCell? {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("statsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StatsViewCell

    // First cell for best scorer 
    // Second cell for best passer
    return cell

}
```

In the **final_query**,

Comment: `combined = [q1: q2]`...

Comment: If I try this it will give me a NSDictionnary, no ?

Comment: How are you wanting to concatenate them... and what is currently returned from each query?

Comment: I would like the name of the best scorer and the name of the best passer. In my class, every player has a field named "goals" and "passes". I just want the row (the "name" field) with the highest int in column "goals" and the row with the highest int in the "passes" field

Comment: To understand, you sort by "goals", you take the first row and then you sort by "passes", you take the first row and you have the two players. Thus, in a collectionView, I'll print in the first cell the best scorer and in the second cell the best passer...

Comment: Maybe show the output of the query above; from what you've described it sounds like you want to create an array or dictionary from the returned values, but then again maybe not.

Comment: What do you want precisely with "output of the query" ? :)

Comment: Are you asking me why I'm asking?

Comment: No absolutely not ^^ I just want to know  what you expected from me, what I have to show you in my query...

Comment: Ah, okay - I think what you've added to your question helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let query = PFQuery(className : "SportsPlayers") // Im assuming your classname change it as needed 

// for highest  scorer 
query.orderByDescending("goals")
query.limit = 1 

// for highest passes
query.orderByDescending("passes")
query.limit = 1
```

Comment: you shoulf do query.limit = 1 after ordering it descending .

Comment: With your solution, we can have in the same time the best scorer and passer no ?

Comment: for more information on queries check out parse docs 
https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found a solution. I don't need to use queryForCollection and concatenate queries but create a query and use findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock function in every cell of my collectionView.